# DoDragDrop Stop/Cancel?

Tags: c#, winforms

Forgive the rather poor code here.

I have a picture box `PictureBox` and a section `Panel`.  I am trying to start a drag and drop operation so you click and drag the picture box, and dropping it into the Section creates a copy.  This is fine.

But the problem is, lets say you click the picture box 9 times, no drag, just clicks. Then on the 10th turn, you do a correct drag and drop operation.... Then you get 10 duplicates added to the Section.

I am guessing that I need to respond to when a DragAndDrop is invalid and stop the drag and drop operation to prevent these duplicate buildups, but I do not know where to look to achieve this.

```
private void collectablePictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.SelectedSection.AllowDrop = true;
    this.SelectedSection.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(this.CollectableSelectedSection_DragEnter);
    this.SelectedSection.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(this.CollectableSelectedSection_DragDrop);
    this.collectablePictureBox.DoDragDrop(this.SelectedClassModel, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}

private void CollectablePictureBox_QueryContinueDrag(object sender, QueryContinueDragEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Action);
}

private void CollectableSelectedSection_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

private void CollectableSelectedSection_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Point position = this.SelectedSection.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    position.X -= this.SelectedClassModel.Width >> 1;
    position.Y -= this.SelectedClassModel.Height >> 1;

    this.SelectedSection.AllowDrop = false;
    this.SelectedSection.DragEnter -= this.CollectableSelectedSection_DragEnter;
    this.SelectedSection.DragDrop -= this.CollectableSelectedSection_DragDrop;

    this.SelectedSection.AddItem(this.SelectedClassModel, position, this.SectionCanvasSnapToGridCheckBox.Checked);

}
```

Comment: Curious: What is a 'Section'?

Comment: Sorry TaW good call. I added it. Section is a `Panel`

Comment: Subscribing the events in the MouseDown event is very wrong.  You must do this only once, it belongs in your constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that on every MouseDown event you add handlers to the appropriate events, so when you actually do the Drag and Drop those handlers will be called more than once. Currently I see two different ways of solving this:

One way to solve the problem would be to not start the Drag and Drop on the MouseDown event handler, but - based on this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article -  start it in a MouseMove handler instead, like this:

```
private void collectablePictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != null && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        this.SelectedSection.AllowDrop = true;
        this.SelectedSection.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(this.CollectableSelectedSection_DragEnter);
        this.SelectedSection.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(this.CollectableSelectedSection_DragDrop);
        this.collectablePictureBox.DoDragDrop(this.SelectedClassModel, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
}
```

Another way would be to also handle the MouseUp event of the PictureBox, and do a similar cleanup as in your `CollectableSelectedSection_DragDrop` handler.